# How to get rid of staggered NA values

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to take data that looks like this:

```
Precinct Office    Votes
1        auditor   10
1        president 9
2        auditor   6
2        president 8
```

to have 3 columns, `precinct`, `auditor` and `president`, with the values being what is now `Votes`. I have tried using `dplyr::spread()`, but end up with something like this:

```
Precinct auditor president
1        10      NA
1        NA      9
2        6       NA
2        NA      8
```

How do I get rid of the staggered `NA`s so that I have half as many rows, like this:

```
Precinct auditor president
1        10      9
2        6       8
```

Comment: Just do `df1 %>% group_by(Precinct) %>% summarise_all(min, na.rm = TRUE)` or `df1 %>% group_by(Precinct) %>% summarise_all(na.omit)`

Comment: Based on the input data showed, `spread(df1, Office, Votes)` gives me the expected output rather than having some NA values

Comment: I can't reproduce your result with NA's.  `tidyr::spread(dat, Office, Votes)` works for me on your dataset to get the desired result.  Can you add the code you used?

Comment: [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: `spread(df, Office, Votes)` is what I was using, but pairing that with `df %>% group_by(Precinct) %>% summarise_all(min, na.rm = TRUE)` from @akrun worked.

Comment: Are there any other variables in your real dataset?  Is your dataset grouped?  I'm using tidyr 0.8.1 and your code works fine for me.  It seems like some information is missing. If you want to get to the bottom of it try adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your question, including the output of `dput(head(df))` and your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [complete.cases](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)

```
df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

Comment: Removes all rows